# Displaying Active directory extended properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The following script is using the Active Directory extended properties to filter the results correctly as it only shows AD users where "script_ignore" is in the 'info' field (this is the 'Notes' field on the Telephones tab in AD users & computers).

However it doesn't display any extended properties as I'd expected in the following foreach-object %_info or $_city.

How can I output extended properties?

```
get-aduser -filter { info -like "script_ignore" } | % {
    $_.name + " " + $_.city + " " + $_.info
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add any property you're interested in which are not included in the default property set, in the Properties parameter.

```
get-aduser -filter { info -like "script_ignore" }  -Properties City,Info | % {
    $_.name + " " + $_.city + " " + $_.info
}
```